# Nearest-neighbor image sampling in 3D WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d, render

I'm desperately trying to render images onto a 3D surface in WPF using nearest-neighbor sampling.  Below is an example of what I currently have, in all its blurriness.  The ImageBrush is given a 64x64 texture.

[image: Sample image.]

I've tried decorating the XAML with `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` everywhere from the `Window` to the `ImageBrush` without fortune.  I've tried writing a custom pixel shader, and couldn't get a satisfactory result.  It even appears that I cannot set the texture sampler's filtering mode from within the shader code.  I've considered work-arounds, such as scaling up the source texture myself, but this would still leave artifacts at two of the edges where it begins interpolating into the next pixel.

Bottom line: Is there any way I can accomplish the effect of nearest neighbor image sampling on a 3D model in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367928/mipmapping-in-wpf) provides a workaround.

You can use a VisualBrush with an Image then WPF will respect the BitmapScalingMode on the image. You can also set the CachingHint (also on RenderOptions) which might improve performance (did not measure it though).

```
var image = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.png")) };
RenderOptions.SetCachingHint(image, CachingHint.Cache);
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
var material = new DiffuseMaterial(new VisualBrush(image));
```

That works for simple scenes, as I said I didn't measure the performance, but I imagine the VisualBrush will hurt for bigger stuff (compared to an ImageBrush). Personally I'll switch over to [Direct3D interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and render the scene via [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) when I hit that problem.